# Cocoapod library - Maintaining Multiple versions

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a library that i published with coco pods, that i want to redesign and publish a new version.

The current version of the pod is 1.2.9.

I publish my new redesign version with a higher version number, something like 2.0.0, but if there is a bug or issue with the old version that i need to fix i want to keep maintaining the old version.

Is there a way that I publish a redesign version but can keep pushing an old version fixes versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set ranges for a different version on your podfile.

We can take your pod as an example.
Your new version is anything above `2.0`, and the old version is anything below that. so you can keep updating the old version to `1.3`, `1.3.1`, `1.3.2` and so on.

What you need to do, is to guide your users to add the appropriate line to their podfile:

```
# Old version
pod 'YourPodName', '< 2.0'

# New version
pod 'YourPodName', '>= 2.0'
```